# how to add pull to refresh to a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm relatively inexperienced with flutter/dart and working on a project of wrapping an app around an existing website. I'm using this repo as a starting point (https://github.com/bettysteger/flutter_pwa_wrapper). That being said, I'd like to add a "pull to refresh" option to the app, but I can't seem to get anything to work so far. All the samples I've seen look simple enough, but I can't seem to mash them into a working set of code so far. I'm hoping someone can help me get there.

I cleaned out my failed attempts and am including the base code. I think this is where it needs to happen:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: SETTINGS.title,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.